# closure by typealias not send data

Tags: swift, xcode, closures, type-alias

I decided to practice a little with typealias closure, but I had a problem that view is not receiving data from the presenter. The code works in an incomprehensible way to me. I already have a typealias closure that transfers data when the user passes permission to get the location, and it works. When I insert my function to transfer data to this working typealias closure, I get the data in view, but I should remove the writing of this function in the working closure and create a new function, then I no longer receive the data. Why is that?

Below I will attach the working and non-working code

```
func chartsIt() {
    viewModel.charts = { [weak self] chartsData in
       self?.chartsView.data = chartsData
       print(chartsData)
       }
   }

func location() {
    self.viewModel.completion = { [weak self] item, one in
   //self?.viewModel.createCharts(item.map { $0.date}, self?.goals ?? [0.0])
 **if you leave this line commented out the chartsIt function will not work**
}
```

in presenter(viewmodel) code:

```
typealias chartsData = (ChartData) -> Void
let players = ["Ozil”, “Ramsey”, “Laca”, “Auba”, “Xhaka”, “Torreira"]
let goals = [6.0, 8.0, 26.0, 30.0, 8.0, 10.0]
var charts: chartsData?
var completion: type?

func byLocation(lat: Double, lon: Double) {

let Operator = Init(test: Test(str: nil, key: nil, lat: lat, lon: lon))

    NetworkService.request(router: Operator.geoLocate()) { [weak self] data in
    if let key = data["Key"].string {
        guard let int = Int(key) else { return }
        self?.weatherFiveDayRequest(key: int) { item, one in
        self?.weather = item
        self?.completion?(item,one)
        }
    }
}
}
func weatherFiveDayRequest(key: Int, completion: @escaping (type)) {
**off-topic code**
    }

 func createCharts(_ dataPoints: [String], _ values: [Double]) {
    guard let charts = charts else { return }
    var dataEntry: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    for item in 0..<dataPoints.count {
    let dataEnter = BarChartDataEntry(x: values[item], y: Double(item))
    dataEntry.append(dataEnter)
    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntry, label: "Units Sold")
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    charts(chartData)
    }
}
//here trigger byLocation () function
init(data: NetworkService) {
self.NetworkService = data
super.init()
locationManager = LocationManager(locationResponse: { item in
    print(item.coordinate.latitude)
    self.byLocation(lat: item.coordinate.latitude, lon: item.coordinate.latitude)
})
```

How can I fix this and get existing data?

Comment: Your code is very confusing. A part of the confusion is that a type alias is a **type** so it should be declared uppercased: `typealias ChartsData = (ChartData) -> Void`. And even `ChartsData` and `ChartData` is confusing. And what is `type`?

Comment: @vadian https://imgur.com/gallery/ePJMiP1 i attached all the code here

Comment: @vadian chartData is just a charting framework (it's a data type of a framework), Convertible is the most common data initializer

Comment: @vadian
I also could not understand why my completion was optional in the byLocation () function, and the createCharts unwrap function was not required. Maybe this is somehow connected?

Comment: @vadian 
please see my topic, I showed my logic easier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163732/closure-through-typealias-swift-not-working