# closure through typealias swift not working

Tags: swift, xcode, closures

why does typealias closure not transmit data and output nothing to the console? How to fix it?

```
class viewModel: NSObject {
    var abc = ["123", "456", "789"]
    typealias type = ([String]) -> Void
    var send: type?

    func createCharts(_ dataPoints: [String]) {
        var dataEntry: [String] = []
        for item in dataPoints {
            dataEntry.append(item)
        }
        send?(dataEntry)
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.createCharts(abc)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var viewModel: viewModel = viewModel()

    func type() {
        viewModel.send = { item in
            print(item)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("hello")
        type()
    }
}
```

I have a project in which a similar design works, but I can not repeat it

Comment: Unrelated, but I might suggest giving the view model class a name that starts with an uppercase letter. It’s really nice to be able to immediately differentiate between the instantiation of some object, e.g. `let bar = Foo()`, vs the calling of some function, e.g. `let bar = foo()`.

Comment: @Rob thank you, I will take this into account!

Answer (score 2):

The pattern is fine, but the timing is off.

You’re calling `createCharts` during the `init` of the view model. But the view controller is setting the `send` closure after the `init` of the view model is done.

Bottom line, you probably don’t want to call `createCharts` during the `init` of the view model.

Comment: A timer technically would do it, but it’s not the right approach. The question is what is the appropriate trigger to call `createCharts`. Maybe the view controller should call it. Or maybe you should have a `start` method in your view model that does it. Or maybe the setter for the view model’s closure should have observer that calls it. You’ve made the example so abstract that it’s kind of hard to advise...

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to create custom initializer:

```
class viewModel: NSObject {
    ...
    init(send: type?) {
        self.send = send
        self.createCharts(abc)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var viewModel: viewModel = viewModel(send: { print($0) })
    ...
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. It works. My project had a similar implementation, but I just couldn’t repeat it